# Collecting inventory from Form Submissions

Tags: forms, asp-classic, submission, collect

I created an activity form using .ASP, by activity form I mean a form where people can select the activities they want to participate in. I would like to know if there is way to collect the submission data where it automatically collects inventory of each activity. The problem is that we have only a certain amount of slots for each activity and would like an easy way in knowing when the slots are filled rather than adding several different submissions.

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions. Also, please forgive me if I am not explaining this properly or using the correct development terminology.

Answer (score 0):

fix the no. of enteries in database of individual activity.
Ex. suppose you want that "action" activity has only 5 required
    then one table of action that will hold only 5 enteries.

Answer (score 0):

Add an integer column to you database table called something like "Places" or "Availability", enter the number of places initially available, then whenever anyone books have your ASP script execute a query along the lines on "Update activities set Places = (Places-1)".  Then, set up your booking page so that it only displays activities with an availibility of greater than 0